# "I done give it up"

Tags: grammar

> Been prospecting up there, but that stream's about panned out. Old Plugger and I **done give it up**.  We're going on back into town.

Is this sentence grammatical? I saw it today in the movie A Million Ways to Die in the West (about 20 minutes in). The man who said it is a prospector. He gave up digging gold. Is "done" here an adverb or this is a special construction?

Comment: Before I give my answer, are you sure about this? It's basically the first time I read it that way..especially with "done"..

Comment: @Sara : sure about what?

Comment: Or maybe I "won't" give it up, because in the case of giving up you mainly say "  I will not give it up " or "I do not give up" what you asked is sort of vague

Comment: Characters in movies often say "ungrammatical" sentences to make them sound like they have a certain cultural background. I probably wouldn't say, "I done give it up," but it wouldn't faze me if a movie character did.

Comment: Could it have been something else such as: "I['m] done; give it up" or ... "I['m] done giving up"???.

Comment: Dunno why others are surprised by this. I've heard it. Some people speak like that. It means *I have given it up*. Whether you want to consider it "acceptable" or not is up to you.

Comment: @snailboat: Sorry, I forgot. I just did

Comment: Completive *done* in AAVE and Southern vernacular AmE is typically followed by a past participle.  The *A Handbook of Varieties of English* says "This auxiliary *done* in a verb phrase may aspectually mark a completed action or event, and may also designate intensity." (p.235) and gives the following examples: "He **done asked** her to marry him" "I **done told** you to take your shoes off before walkin' on that carpet".

Comment: However, the character's dialect and usage are somewhat different from this.  Searching [COHA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/?c=coha&q=32982867), I see that historically *done* + plain present was more common, although whether the examples are genuine is questionable (they seem to appear in stereotyped dialogue).  I can find a fair number of examples from 1880-1920.  Perhaps the dialogue genuinely fits the dialect the character would have had at that time and place.  I can't say; I'm unfamiliar with the details of the dialect in question.

Comment: @snailboat Do you have a pdf copy of that book?

Comment: @Man_From_India I suggest checking Google Books or a library.  It's too expensive to reasonably suggest getting your own copy.

Comment: @snailboat yea :)

Answer (score 6):

"I done give it up" is US southern speech, from someone who is not "book educated". It is a kind of emphatic perfect tense that means "I have given it up."

```
> I said, give your brother back his hat!
> --But I done give it to him, pa. He's a dirty liar to say I still got it.
```

Comment: I kind of like it when they go "ungrammatical"  because they're not "book educated" and you're basically correct

Comment: @Tim Romano: The movie is about the West, the American
frontier.

Comment: @quantana43: The frontier (the "Wild West") was a place inhabited only by indigenous native Americans at first.  Americans of European descent, and later, to a lesser extent, from Africa, "went west". One would have heard (still hears today) many southernisms there.

Comment: @quintana43: sorry for misspelling your handle.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "standard" American English. This kind of construction is sometimes seen in subsets of American English such as "Black" English.

A better (or at least more conventional) construction is I *did* give it up.